# social-auth-app-django facebook backend state with redirect_uri

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I know my question sounds like a duplicate, but I've looked everywhere without finding any solution.

I am working on implementing social logins for my django webapp. So far google, twitter and yahoo logins have worked as expected. But facebook always gives the error below:

URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

After some digging I got to learn how to setup my facebook login properly: Facebook app settings below

`App Domains` set to `domain.ext`

`Site URL` set to `https://www.domain.ext/`

`Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` set to `https://domain.ext/social/complete/facebook/`

I also looked at the redirect url (shown below) and found that it contains a `state` variable, `state=kMQH3TdKSdF8oYGGx7Xri4KgFaEQ9OyU`. Full url below

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=977674249054153&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.ext%2Fsocial%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F&state=kMQH3TdKSdF8oYGGx7Xri4KgFaEQ9OyU&return_scopes=true&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile`

My facebook login url on my django app is `{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}` and I have this `'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2'` in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

I searched and found there's such issue already on the `social-core` github page which has been resolved. It says that from v1.7.0, this line `REDIRECT_STATE = False` has been added to the facebook backend. I dug into the sourcecode and found that to be the case. But my app's url keep sending the state variable and I have no idea why that is the case. Please has someone else encountered this odd behaviour, and if yes how did you go about working it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent hours on this issue, but it turns out I only needed to do this `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` set to `https://www.domain.ext/social/complete/facebook/`

Note the `www.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried django-allauth? I find it to be a much better solution. It takes care of third party provider integration for you with builtin support for many providers and custom providers.