# Getting “URL Blocked” error on Facebook login on production server using Nginx and Django

Tags: django, facebook, nginx, oauth, production

I'm using Django OAuth (`social-auth-app-django`) for Facebook login. It works on `localhost` but after some time it stopped working on a production server.
When I push the Facebook login button (https:///oauth/login/facebook/
) on production server, I get redirected to this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=2125271371046613&state=ngamzlnEBNjkivjZkZDJWyPi7MnyJ6z5&return_scopes=true&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F
```

with the following message:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

My Valid OAuth Redirect URIs is: `https://<my domain>/oauth/complete/facebook/`

It appears that Django generates `redirect_uri=https://localhost/auth/complete/facebook/` instead of `redirect_uri=https://<my domain>/auth/complete/facebook/`

Also, if I add `https://localhost/oauth/complete/facebook/` to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs and push Facebook login button, I am redirected to

```
https://localhost/oauth/complete/facebook/?granted_scopes=public_profile&denied_scopes&code=AQDVoyWYftr-kU55VpWzUlyVOaFu80nWrdNhvnnakA-zxWRlGjwbBC4DMGyKasgDYtgtiPieqxO2H0H3z7mh-OxRuniJBDVOftCWnPNEKGfn8Tf-XExxYOcWdwAjhSUltgpm152fM13mgSDEGlzRvv6Dn_ccImV3c9Wsjr756jLdZr5cAdtIxv6tWLBsEBlynJmDZEYiucszOpain80WJCjAQAvyf3JdoCE0pb-YaxMFVa9c8KcN58s9Uif12trCc772AMQXnXDJxPauBl65bO5kRMJ4HPSj_-SXrMflWj5idehmM5OwsSGJakKsXgeYkshjnYycmc9bsy6NxAykV515&state=ngamzlnEBNjkivjZkZDJWyPi7MnyJ6z5#_=_
```

and (obviously) get “server not found” message. However, if I then manually change `localhost` to `<my domain>` like this:

```
https://<my domain>/oauth/complete/facebook/?granted_scopes=public_profile&denied_scopes&code=AQDVoyWYftr-kU55VpWzUlyVOaFu80nWrdNhvnnakA-zxWRlGjwbBC4DMGyKasgDYtgtiPieqxO2H0H3z7mh-OxRuniJBDVOftCWnPNEKGfn8Tf-XExxYOcWdwAjhSUltgpm152fM13mgSDEGlzRvv6Dn_ccImV3c9Wsjr756jLdZr5cAdtIxv6tWLBsEBlynJmDZEYiucszOpain80WJCjAQAvyf3JdoCE0pb-YaxMFVa9c8KcN58s9Uif12trCc772AMQXnXDJxPauBl65bO5kRMJ4HPSj_-SXrMflWj5idehmM5OwsSGJakKsXgeYkshjnYycmc9bsy6NxAykV515&state=ngamzlnEBNjkivjZkZDJWyPi7MnyJ6z5#_=_
```

I then have a successful login.

How to make Django (or probably Nginx) generate a `redirect_uri` with `<my domain>` instead of `localhost`?

I know this looks like a duplicate of [social-auth-app-django facebook backend state with redirect_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363059/social-auth-app-django-facebook-backend-state-with-redirect-uri), but they already had proper `redirect_uri` in their case.

Here are my Nginx settings:

```
upstream citizen_engagement_portal {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/volunteer/xxx/yyy.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <my domain> www.<my domain>;

    root /home/volunteer/xxx;

    location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/volunteer/serve;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/volunteer/xxx/yyy.sock;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
    }

    # security headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my domain>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = <my domain>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name <my domain> www.<my domain>;

    location / {
        return 301 https://<my domain>$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested by @omab [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782979/django-social-auth-redirect-uri-invalid)

> `django-social-auth` uses `request.build_absolute_uri()` to build that `redirect_uri` parameter. Checking django code for `build_absolute_uri()` it calls `get_host()` which checks for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`, `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME`.
>   Try defining any of those headers in your location recipe (I think there's a proxy_set_header for that).

I did that. In `/etc/nginx/proxy_params`

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host '<my domain>';
```

In Django `settings.py`

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

If I understand correctly, Django backend did not know that it is hosted at `<my domain>` and I made Nginx tell Django that.